# Drawing a Drawable from ImageView.getDrawable() within a BitmapDrawable

Tags: java, android

The goal is this: Get the current `Drawable` in the `ImageView`, replace it with a `BitmapDrawable` backed by a new image which also contains the old, then apply modularized transitions between them. Basically just:

```
TransitionDrawable extends BitmapDrawable
    Drawable old;
    List<TransitionModules> modules

    draw(Canvas)
        applyExitModules()
        old.draw(canvas)
        applyEntranceModules()
        super.draw(canvas)
```

Now, calling `old.draw(canvas)` does draw the old image, but some augmentations (e.g. `Canvas.setMatrix(Matrix)` or `Drawable.setAlpha(int)`) don't seem to take effect when the old is another `TransitionDrawable` (likely because of the overridden draw(Canvas), I believe). However, scaling and translations on the Canvas work as expected.

As a note, the modules/drawing work properly on the entrance animation, but I believe that's because the transition properties are applied to the `BitmapDrawable` which is drawing itself correctly when called.

**What works**:

```
Canvas.rotate
Canvas.scale
Canvas.translate
```

**What doesn't**:

```
Drawable.setAlpha (including attempts at applying the Alpha to the TransitionDrawable itself, then reverting)
Canvas.setMatrix
```

**TL;DR**: why do some of the above transitional properties affect the drawing of `Drawable.draw(Canvas)`, yet the others I listed do not?

Comment: if you cannot do what you want using a std `TransitionDrawable` you can always create your own custom `Drawable` class and draw whatever you want in its `draw` method

Comment: This actually is a custom Drawable; my TransitionDrawable is an extension of a BitmapDrawable and has no connection to the TransitionDrawable from the SDK. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: then you have free hand of doing whatever you like... so whats the problem actually? maybe post your Drawable? btw if you want to see how various animation can be applied to a `Drawable` take a look [here](https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable)

Comment: The problem is the certain augmentations to the canvas/drawable aren't working when the 'from' is an instance of the TransitionDrawable. Here's a link to the latest master: https://github.com/mattsilber/imageloader/blob/master/src/main/java/com/guardanis/imageloader/transitions/drawables/TransitionDrawable.java

Comment: hard to tell, where are you setting the bounds of `oldDrawable` and `targetDrawable`? in `TransitionModule` or something?

Comment: also maybe it would be useful to use std `Animation`s like it was done [here](https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable)? just a wild guess...

Comment: I actually don't set the bounds, I just offset the drawings based on the differences between them, else the image could visually change during the initial switching of the Drawable. I think I might have just isolated the issue to be the recursive call to TransitionDrawable's draw() since the child submodule(s) are working directly with the same Canvas so their augmentations may be taking priority. I think I need rethink that bit... And cool lib, checking it out now, thanks for the link

Comment: the most important line is [that](https://github.com/pskink/PatchworkDrawable/blob/master/PatchworkDrawableLibrary/src/org/pskink/patchworkdrawable/drawable/PatchworkDrawable.java#L363) `if` statement (or rather its `else` branch), it applies any built-in `Animation` like AlphaAnimation, RotateAnimation, ScaleAnimation, TranslateAnimation or  any combination of them inside AnimationSet or even your custom one

Comment: I really like that approach using the getTransformation() the way you do it in your PatchworkDrawable, but I'm having trouble finding a way to interpolate between a partially-completed transition and the latest transitions that should apply to it. Any chance you're familiar with that and could point me in the right direction? Thanks again man, you've been a huge help so far

Comment: hmm, honestly i dont really know what you mean by "a way to interpolate between a partially-completed transition and the latest transitions that should apply to it"

Comment: Let's say I have an image to start. A fade/rotate/scale-in transition is applied to a new image as it's added. Then, another request is started for that same ImageView before the previous transition has completed. So now there are technically two transitions occurring. So, the idea is to transition from the last state of the last transition instead of what it would be had the transition completed. With effects lasting <500ms it's pretty negligible, but any kind of elongated transition will cause a noticeable effect

Comment: so this is what Matrix is for: you can concat one with the other, i concat Matrices in my code all the time ;-) the problem can be with alpha thou...

Comment: Very interesting... I'm going to look into all this further. Thanks so much for the help again!

Comment: no problem,  happy learning...

Comment: the code i posted yesterday didnt have one nice feature: `Animation#setFillAfter`, this is a minimalist version: http://pastebin.com/r78xkhvx

Comment: Nice, thanks for the heads up. I guess in my case I actually do want fillAfter enforced, but that link is helpful, thanks again!